# Scala - How to Parse List of Paths into Directory Structure As JSON

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to create a nested directory structure json given a list of filepaths in scala.
For example,

If i have a List of paths like this:

```
 val a= List("/a/b/c/d/e/f/runid1",'
             "/a/b/c/d/e/f/runid2",
             "/a/b/c/d/e/g/runid3",
             "a/b/c/d/e/h/runid4",
              "a/b/c/d/k/i/runid5",
              "a/b/c/d/k/j/runid6",
              "p/t/u/v/w/x/runid7")
```

I would like to parse this structure to create Json. I am currently trying to use json4s.Jackson.serialization.write.

The json I would like in my output would look like this :

```
    {label1:a,
     items:[
      {
        label2:b,
        items:[
               {
                label3:C,
                items:[{
                     label4:d
                     items:[{
                              label5:e,
                              items:[{
                                     f:runid1|runid2,
                                     g:runid3,
                                     h:runid4}]
                              label5:k,
                              items:[{ i:runid5
                                       j:runid6}]
                            }]
                     }]
               }]
      }]
  label1:p
  items:[{
        label2:t
        items:[{
                label3:u
                items:[{
                   label4:v
                   items:[{
                          label5:w
                          items:[{
                                  x:runid7
                                 }]
                        
                           }]
                       }]
             }]
   }
```

I would like to parse the list of files into case classes and create the following json. Any hints would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Comment: Step 1, define some case classes that can represent the hierarchy you want. Step 2, write a function that transforms a `List[String]` into that. Step 3, pick any **Scala** json library _(**Jackson** is NOT  a **Scala** json library)_ to transform that value into a json string.

Comment: Given a set of case classes, I was able to produce json, but not the structure I want. I have a basic case class that creates a linear json, but I would like to create the nested structure above. I was able to get json using json4s.Jackson.serialization.write.